# Seeding SQLite with Devise Model Gives Uniqueness Constraint Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

**Edit**
Really Stupid Mistake:

db:reset seeds the database.

I'm trying to seed a db and create users who have posts but the users keep violating the uniqueness constraint...even if there's only one of them.

At the moment, I have no model validations.

The standard User Devise schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  t.string   "username"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

db/seeds.rb

```
1.times do |n|
email                           = Faker::Internet.email 
username                        = Faker::Name.name 
password                        = 'password' 
password_confirmation           = 'password' 
reset_password_token            = nil
id                              = n

User.create!(
    email:                  email,
    username:               username,
    password:               password,
    password_confirmation:  password_confirmation,
    reset_password_token:   reset_password_token,
    id: id          
)
end
```

I have run the following:

```
rails c 
rake db:reset
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
>> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.id: INSERT INTO "users"
```

I have only a single user that is generated but violates the uniqueness.  The stack trace tells me it is a problem with the create method but I'm not sure how to remedy this.

I only have two possible things that need to be unique at the db level and that's the index_users_on_email and index_users_on_reset_password both of which are unique if the db has been reset and seeded with only one record.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I created my seed for Users, hope it helps.

```
1.times do
    user = User.new(
      name:      Faker::Name.name,
      email:     Faker::Internet.email,
      password:  Faker::Lorem.characters(10)
    )
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!
end

users = User.all
```